# Entity Framework 6 & SQL Server reserved keyword to lowercase during generation of SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using other project DLL to your project. For the reference project DLL, SQL Server reserved keyword to be lower case during generation of SQL in Entity Framework 6.

We had tried many ways after that we got only one solution using `IDbCommandInterceptor` as below:

```
public class CustomEFInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        AppendToLog(command);
    }

    private void AppendToLog(DbCommand command)
    {
        string sqlStr = new StringBuilder(command.CommandText).Replace("INSERT", "insert").Replace("VALUES", "values")
                                                  .Replace("UPDATE", "update").Replace("SET", "set")
                                                  .Replace("DELETE", "delete")
                                                  .Replace("WHERE", "where")
                                                  .Replace("\r\n", " ").ToString();
        //// ..... Added to DB Table and Executed during some other process.
    }
}
```

Is there is any other solution using EF6 Model Builder Conventions or configuration?

```
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
{
    public TestEntities() : base("name=TestEntities3")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care about the casing of the reserved words?

Comment: @Devid: In reference project using Generated SQL, there is some logic to do addition process for this sqlString.Contains("values"), sqlString.IndexOf("values") methods are used lot of places.

Comment: Eg: int strEnd = sqlString.IndexOf("where");

Comment: I would be **very** wary of running code like that. For example, what if the SQL includes a string value with a reserved word? For example `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%where%'`?

Comment: I have added a solution, hope it helps you

Comment: Maybe new StringBuilder(command.CommandText).ToString().ToLowerInvariant() is best way?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of handling sql keywords, you can also find the index case-insensitively.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%reyan%'";
int index = sql.IndexOf("where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // index = 24
```

You can even create extension method for this.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string statement, string word, StringComparison stringComparison)
    {
        return statement?.IndexOf(word, stringComparison) >= 0;
    }
}


string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%reyan%'";
bool contains = sql.Contains("where", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // contains = true
```

But again as suggested by David, if any of your word matches with sql keyword then you would get the index of that word as well.